# how to locate element with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

After exporting a test in Visual Studio using Selenium webdriver, I execute the test case in VS and it fails when trying to locate an element in the test. The element is a tab within a page but the test case cannot find the id of the tab. This is the failing line `driver.FindElement(By.Id("ui-id-14")).Click();` and I also tried to locate the element with the ClassName `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-tabs-anchor")).Click();` by inspecting the element in Chrome browser but it still fails. Anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ui-id-14")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-tabs-anchor")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

How Do you initalize you driver? A common mistake is not having a implicit wait with selenium. The driver tries to locate the element as soon as the document is ready, which is not feasible with "normal" JS applications as they are rendered after the document is ready. Try:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This way the driver will try to find the element every 0.5 seconds up to 30 seconds before throwing an Exception. By the way: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider posting your code/code snippets, that makes analysis often easier. My suggestion is purely made from my experience with people being new to Selenium.